# Powershell function with Try...Catch not making it into the function, because the parameter causes an error

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to use a function to confirm or deny whether or not we made it past a cmdlet without an error -- I'm running a bunch of AD/Exchange cmdlets and am storing/outputting the results to .csv at the end. I forgot to import the Exchange module, which worked to my benefit since it terminated in a way I wasn't expecting when I used Get-DistributionList.

I've tried using $? in place of the Try..Catch, forcing the EA to be stop, and storing the parameter in a variable first, but since the module isn't installed and the cmdlet isn't recognized it just stops the program.

Here's essentially what I want to do:

```
function Test-Success ($cmdlet){
    try{
          $cmdlet
          "Y"
    } catch {
          "Err -- Perform manually."
    }
}

Test-Success(Get-DistributionList)
```

But I get the following error, and the script stops:

```
Get-DistributionList : The term 'Get-DistributionList' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script
file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct
and try again.
At line:46 char:10
+ Test-Success(Get-DistributionList)
+          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-DistributionList:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Worst case scenario, I can just place the try...catch in every time, as it seems to work that way (example:)

```
try {
     Get-DistributionList
     "y"
} catch {
     "Err -- Perform manually"
}
```

Any help is appreciated!I'm hoping there is a workaround so that it won't terminate the program if a cmdlet fails in this way, but I'm not terribly familiar with PowerShell and my own searches have been inconclusive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just looking to see if the command exists, you should use `Get-Command` like @DimplesMcGibble suggested.  If you are trying to execute the command, you can pass the command name as a string and use the invoke-operator

```
function Test-Success ($cmdlet){
    try{
          & $cmdlet
          "Y"
    } catch {
          "Err -- Perform manually."
    }
}

Test-Success 'Get-DistributionList'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `Get-Command` to check for the existence of a given cmdlet without the `try\catch`